# Tkinter vertical scrollbar doesn't work functionally, it only shows small bar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I need to add a vertical scroll bar for the "treeview_1" which is inside a grid.

Basically, I created a grid.
Inside a grid

so, my solution is at this part

```
# scrollbar
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=treeview_1.yview)
    vsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", columnspan=2)
    treeview_1.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
```

this is the result,
[image]

This is not a functional scrollbar ..., even though I fill in data.

Comment: The scrollbar isn't growing as much as its parent, you have to spread it from north to south, so `sticky='ns'` instead of `sticky='e'`

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided is correct. If you're not seeing scroll bars in your development environment while running this code, you may need to check your environment settings or preferences to enable or show scroll bars. The code you provided doesn't influence the appearance of scroll bars. I have a code to create a scroll bar in Tkinter, I hope it will help you.

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_text_with_content(root):
    text = tk.Text(root, wrap=tk.NONE, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    text.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    for i in range(20):
        text.insert(tk.END, f"Line {i}\n")

    return text

def on_scroll(*args):
    text.yview_moveto(args[0])

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)

text_widget = create_text_with_content(root)
text_widget.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=on_scroll)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried working on your code it worked as a reference is good and easy to understand

Comment: Right now, the variable `text` isn't defined in `on_scroll`. Also `args[0]` should actually be `args[1]`. Both of these problems can be avoided just by using `command=text_widget.yview` instead of defining your own function.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no person wants to answer this question, I have to do some research for myself.

Luckily, there is an answer:

```
vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=treeview_1.yview)
vscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NSE")
treeview_1.configure(yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
```

The core issue here is the sticky option, it can be north-south-east which is exactly "NSE".

Done.

Answer (score -1):

Please find my example. It might help you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Vertical Scrollbar Example")

# Create a grid
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10")
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S))

# Create a Treeview widget
treeview_1 = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=("Column 1", "Column 2"), show="headings")
treeview_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# Add some sample data to the Treeview
treeview_1.heading("Column 1", text="Column 1")
treeview_1.heading("Column 2", text="Column 2")

for i in range(1, 21):
    treeview_1.insert("", "end", values=(f"Item {i}", f"Description {i}"))

# Create a vertical scrollbar
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=treeview_1.yview)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
treeview_1.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

# Allow the Treeview and the Scrollbar to expand with the window
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Run the application
root.mainloop()
```